# Build: Cannot find type definition file for 'q'

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

Followed the instructions here: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Had problems with restoring package, but suddenly it worked after restarting the computer.

But now I have a "Build: Cannot find type definition file for 'q'" error when building.

Comment: you will probably need to include declarations for q. Have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html